# Print from an Electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, electron

I'm trying to use [node printer](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer) from an Electron application, but as soon I add the lines to use the printer, the app crashes.

The console outputs this:

```
[1]    9860 segmentation fault (core dumped)  node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron.
```

This is the app I'm running:

```
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
var printer = require('printer');

require('crash-reporter').start();

app.on('ready', function() {
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
  mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/app/index.html');

  mainWindow.openDevTools();

  printer.printDirect({data:"print from Node.JS buffer" // or simple String: "some text"
      , printer:'HP-Deskjet-F4400-series' // printer name, if missing then will print to default printer
      , type: 'TEXT' // type: RAW, TEXT, PDF, JPEG, .. depends on platform
      , success:function(jobID){
          console.log("sent to printer with ID: "+jobID);
      }
      , error:function(err){console.log(err);}
  });      
});
```

Am I missing something?

I tried the node printer on its own, and I successfully printed some gibberish text.

Answer (score 9):

`node-printer` uses native bindings and according to the [docs](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md):

> The native Node modules are supported by Electron, but since Electron
>   is using a different V8 version from official Node, you have to
>   manually specify the location of Electron's headers when building
>   native modules.

I suppose that is why you are getting the `seg fault`. Try to build the module against the electron headers as mentioned in the docs:

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

# Every time you run npm install, run this too
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

Comment: Did it with no success. This is what it happens now:

`npm ERR! Failed at the printer@0.1.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
 npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the printer package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
 npm ERR! You can get their info via:
 npm ERR!     npm owner ls printer
 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.`

Comment: @leamasuero See the docs, there is also another way using the node-gyp. maybe that helps.

Comment: @leamasuero, the last time I had this error, I solved it by downgrading my node version to `8.x.x`.

Answer (score 7):

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, resizable: false})
  win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html')
  win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win.webContents.printToPDF({marginsType: 2, pageSize: "A3", landscape: false}, (error, data) => {
      if (error) throw error
      fs.writeFile('output.pdf', data, (error) => {

        //getTitle of Window
        console.log(win.webContents.getTitle())

        //Silent Print

        if (error) throw error
        console.log('Write PDF successfully.')
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Otherwise You can also use the following line

```
win.webContents.print({silent:true, printBackground:true})
```

Comment: `writeFile('output.pdf'...)` doesnt work but the bottom one does!

Answer (score 5):

The `node-printer` module has C++ code in it. Which means that you have to compile it using the same version of node that electron is using. This is doable actually, but it is pretty complicated.

On the other hand, Electron already has printing API's in it:

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsprintoptions-callback

If this api isn't sufficient and you still want to leverage the `node-printer` module let me know and I will edit this response with a longer answer about how to fork and fix `node-printer` so that it is electron compatible.

Comment: having `node-printer` compatible with electron requires to port it to `NAN 2`, is that correct?

Comment: What I mean is that Electron now uses `node v4` and V8 api changed quite a lot.

Comment: Yeah I think so. I had a similar situation with a different package and I had to fork it to implement the changes I needed to get it to build with electron. Most of the changes were superficial... most of them.

Comment: The node-printer in not working for me on windows. It is only workable if I want to print simple text or some RAW data. Buy fails to print any JPEG or PDF. Have you tested it on windows ?

Comment: No I haven't tested it at all. I don't know what the capabilities are.

Comment: i ended up finding it under webContents. thanks nonetheless

Comment: legendary beard btw