# Using VB based Visual Studio project with AngularJS/HTML5

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, vbscript

My  goal  is  to  write  a  desktop  application  created  through  Visual  Studio  which  uses  HTML5  and  AngularJS  to  display  a  well  put  together  front  end  to  the  user  but  which  also  allows  for  me  to  use  VBscript so  I  can  do  read/write items,  send  things  to  the  printer,  and  compose/send  emails  from  their  outlook  automatically.

Can  this  be  done  and  which  options  should  I  select  when  starting  my project?  I  can  not  have  this  run  through  a  traditional  web  browser  since  I  am  doing  the  above  mentioned  items  which  browsers  won't  let  me  do.

p.s.  I  just  download  VS  2015  community  today.  I  have  spent  the  day  researching  and  finding  lots  of  helpful  information  but  nothing  which  answers  this.

Comment: As much as ill take that under consideration, VBA/script is what i know and learned from. I can jimmy-rig js to work for me but i need to churn out a solution for our team ASAP, so i would prefer to do the system access stuff in vbscript. With thag being said, can someone provide an answer to my inquiry? Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft ended VBScript suppport on IE11 and then IE's itself. Of course legacy support will continue for a while but even you create an HTML application running in IE10 or IE9 mode (not IE8 due to [AngularJS kindly ignores IE8](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)) you'll have to deal with tons of compatibility issues, registry hacks, administration elevation requirements and so on. Plus, all of these configurations will be easily broken by the users. Wouldn't be good to use Visual Basic.Net to interact with your HTML page? How VBScript is essential for this project?

Comment: You want a kind of "backend" with VB / VBS and a frontend with HTML5/AngularJS, but without scripting in JavaScript. Is VB.Net also a possible solution? VB can create Web Controls and navigate them / manipulate their DOM. ...Just to clear it up and don't repeat what others already said

Comment: So, have you looked into Electron ?

Answer (score 1):

### You don't need VBScript

You should check out [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/), with which you can develop desktop applications in Javascript / HTML5, and maybe, an [AngularJS - Electron seed project](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular2-seed-advanced) to speed things up.

Now if you consider Electron, you can check out [this answer about printing with Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274265/print-from-electron-application).

If you want to persist in this (which seems to be the best course of action in my opinion), you can find any informations about how to do this and that with electron by [reading the docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/tree/master/docs), [tutorials](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/desktop-environment-integration.md) and [basic google searches](https://www.google.fr/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=how+to+configure+electron+in+visual+studio&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=fE1RV-iRMsv_acqQj5gD).

Don't hesitate to come back to SO if you have precise questions regarding code you already have.