# Electron Application - how to print the current page

Tags: electron, atom-editor, electron-builder

I have an electron app built, it is basically a form.

When a user clicks finish on the form, their details get registered remotely but it is also essential that an A4 printout of the electron app screen gets sent to the default computer.

Is this at all possible with electron, I imagined it would work the same way as simply clicking ctrl+p on chrome but it doesnt work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274265/print-from-an-electron-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print from an Electron application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274265/print-from-an-electron-application)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible, Check the following:

https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer