# How to use PrintJS to print a local file

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, printjs

I have a function that saves a file locally. I want to use the PrintJS to access the file and print it.

The function below is what I have done

```
 $.fn.openPDF = function (id) {
         printJS({ printable: stores + file_path + id + '.pdf', type: 'raw-html' });
         }
```

Instead of printing the content of the file, it rather prints the location of the file.

[image]

I need help...

I want to print the file directly.

Comment: Does this question help? [Print from an Electron application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32274265/996081)

Comment: I think maybe you want `type: 'pdf'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650784/printing-a-pdf-file-with-electron-js/68746358#68746358 This worked for me